# Potential activation functions?

Tags: neural-networks

For 4 inputs (2 bounded positive range, 2 bounded negative to positive range) and 2 outputs (unbounded 0 to inf, bounded negative to positive range), what activation functions can I use for my neural net's output activation layer? I am thinking of using either ELU or Leaky RELU and upon experimentation have found that those 2 yield acceptable results. Are there any other functions I can use for good results?